# How to create a Xaml FlowDocument with Page Headers and Footers when rendered to XPS?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.0, flowdocument

I am looking for an idea of a clean generic way to describe repeating page headers and footers in a XAML FlowDocument without any code behind. It only needs to show up correctly when rendered to XPS from C#.

Comment: By "without any code behind," do you mean that you want to have the headers and footers specified solely through XAML?  I'm not sure that's possible.  The pagination process that converts a FlowDocument to a FixedDocument is going to cut pages as it lays out the FlowDocument content against a fixed page size.  Unless your FlowDocument presumes a page size and lays out its content in fixed sizes accordingly, the pagination process isn't necessarily going to cut pages or place headers & footers where you intend.

Comment: @mcw0933 I'm referring to literal code behind, a cs attached to XAML file, my requirements can assume a page size, but it certainly is possible to put custom data into a XAML file and read out prior to the xps rendering stage to modify paginating.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had the same problem a few months ago, and found these links very helpful:
[WPF Multipage Reports Part IV Pagination](http://web.archive.org/web/20130116205214/http://janrep.blog.codeplant.net/post/WPF-Multipage-Reports-Part-IV-Pagination.aspx)
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/PimpedDocumentPaginator.aspx

The basic technique I used was to create a custom paginator by deriving from `DynamicDocumentPaginator` as follows:

```
internal class HeaderFooterPaginator<THeaderModel, TFooterModel> : DynamicDocumentPaginator where THeaderModel : PageNumberModel, new() where TFooterModel : PageNumberModel, new()
{
...
}
```

In my case, `THeaderFooterModel` and `TFooterModel` are subclasses of a `PageNumberModel` type as I needed the header or footer to be able to show the current page number.

```
public class PageNumberModel
{
    public int PageNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The custom paginator delegates to the original XPS paginator to do the majority of its work, so it stores it away in the constructor.

The `THeaderModel` and `TFooterModel` types allow the paginator to retrieve XAML `DataTemplates` for each type, which is what allows you to specify the layout of the header and footer in XAML without resorting to custom drawing code.

In my code, the header and footer are of a fixed size, so when the paginator is created it retrieves the header and footer templates to determine how much space to reserve.

In the example code in the links provided, the technique they use to reserve space for the header and footer is to use a scale transform to shrink the original content. Instead, I tell the original paginator to use a reduced page size and then add the page the original paginator generates to a `ContainerVisual` and set its `Offset`. You probably couldn't do this if the size of the headers and footers was dynamic because the page count would keep changing.

The only other complication I can recall was that you need to use the `Dispatcher` queue when adding headers and footers (see `AddHeaderOrFooterToContainerAsync` below). Data binding doesn't work otherwise. We are slightly subverting the WPF rendering model to get this to work.

This would all be quite hard to explain without including the code so I've attached the custom renderer code below. I've stripped out some irrelevant stuff so if it doesn't compile as is that's probably why :-)

Note that the page number offset is passed in because our XPS document is comprised of multiple FlowDocument sections and the calling code keeps track of the current overall page number.

Hope this helps!

```
internal class HeaderFooterPaginator<THeaderModel, TFooterModel> : DynamicDocumentPaginator where THeaderModel : PageNumberModel, new() where TFooterModel : PageNumberModel, new()
{
    private readonly double _footerHeight;
    private readonly DataTemplate _footerTemplate;
    private readonly double _headerHeight;
    private readonly DataTemplate _headerTemplate;
    private Size _newPageSize;
    private Size _originalPageSize;
    private readonly DynamicDocumentPaginator _originalPaginator;
    private readonly int _pageNumberOffset;
    private readonly FlowDocument _paginatorSource;
    private const double HeaderAndFooterMarginHeight = 5;
    private const double HeaderAndFooterMarginWidth = 10;

    public HeaderFooterPaginator(int pageNumberOffset, FlowDocument document)
    {
        if (document == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("document");
        }

        _paginatorSource = document;

        if (_paginatorSource == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Could not create a clone of the document being paginated.");
        }

        _originalPaginator = ((IDocumentPaginatorSource) _paginatorSource).DocumentPaginator as DynamicDocumentPaginator;

        if (_originalPaginator == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The paginator must be a DynamicDocumentPaginator.");
        }

        _headerTemplate = GetModelDataTemplate(typeof (THeaderModel));
        _footerTemplate = GetModelDataTemplate(typeof (TFooterModel));

        var headerSize = GetModelContentSize(new THeaderModel { PageNumber = int.MaxValue }, _headerTemplate, _originalPaginator.PageSize);
        var footerSize = GetModelContentSize(new TFooterModel { PageNumber = int.MaxValue }, _footerTemplate, _originalPaginator.PageSize);

        _headerHeight = double.IsInfinity(headerSize.Height) ? 0 : headerSize.Height;
        _footerHeight = double.IsInfinity(footerSize.Height) ? 0 : footerSize.Height;

        _pageNumberOffset = pageNumberOffset;

        SetPageSize(new Size(document.PageWidth, document.PageHeight));
    }

    private void AddHeaderOrFooterToContainerAsync<THeaderOrFooter>(ContainerVisual container, double areaWidth, double areaHeight, Vector areaOffset, FrameworkTemplate template, int displayPageNumber)  where THeaderOrFooter : PageNumberModel, new()
    {
        if (template == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        var visual = GetModelContent(new THeaderOrFooter { PageNumber = displayPageNumber }, template);

        if (visual != null)
        {
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new Action(() =>
            {
                visual.Measure(_originalPageSize);
                visual.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, areaWidth, areaHeight));
                visual.UpdateLayout();

                var headerContainer = new ContainerVisual { Offset = areaOffset };
                headerContainer.Children.Add(visual);
                container.Children.Add(headerContainer);
            }));
        }
    }

    public override void ComputePageCount()
    {
        _originalPaginator.ComputePageCount();
    }

    private static void FlushDispatcher()
    {
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle, new DispatcherOperationCallback(delegate { return null; }), null);
    }

    private static FrameworkElement GetModelContent(object dataModel, FrameworkTemplate modelTemplate)
    {
        if (modelTemplate == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        var content = modelTemplate.LoadContent() as FrameworkElement;
        if (content == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        content.DataContext = dataModel;

        return content;
    }

    private static Size GetModelContentSize(object dataModel, FrameworkTemplate modelTemplate, Size availableSize)
    {
        var content = GetModelContent(dataModel, modelTemplate);
        if (content == null)
        {
            return Size.Empty;
        }

        FlushDispatcher();
        content.Measure(availableSize);
        return content.DesiredSize;
    }

    private DataTemplate GetModelDataTemplate(Type modelType)
    {
        var key = new DataTemplateKey(modelType);
        return _paginatorSource.TryFindResource(key) as DataTemplate;
    }

    public override ContentPosition GetObjectPosition(object value)
    {
        return _originalPaginator.GetObjectPosition(value);
    }

    public override DocumentPage GetPage(int pageNumber)
    {
        if (!_originalPaginator.IsPageCountValid)
        {
            ComputePageCount();
        }

        var originalPage = _originalPaginator.GetPage(pageNumber);

        var newPage = new ContainerVisual();

        var displayPageNumber = _pageNumberOffset + pageNumber;
        var internalWidth = _originalPageSize.Width - 2*HeaderAndFooterMarginWidth;
        AddHeaderOrFooterToContainerAsync<THeaderModel>(newPage, internalWidth, _headerHeight, new Vector(HeaderAndFooterMarginWidth, HeaderAndFooterMarginHeight), _headerTemplate, displayPageNumber);

        var smallerPage = new ContainerVisual();
        smallerPage.Children.Add(originalPage.Visual);
        smallerPage.Offset = new Vector(HeaderAndFooterMarginWidth, HeaderAndFooterMarginHeight + _headerHeight);
        newPage.Children.Add(smallerPage);

        AddHeaderOrFooterToContainerAsync<TFooterModel>(newPage, internalWidth, _footerHeight, new Vector(HeaderAndFooterMarginWidth, _originalPageSize.Height - HeaderAndFooterMarginHeight - _footerHeight), _footerTemplate, displayPageNumber);

        return new DocumentPage(newPage, _originalPageSize, originalPage.BleedBox, originalPage.ContentBox);
    }

    public override int GetPageNumber(ContentPosition contentPosition)
    {
        return _originalPaginator.GetPageNumber(contentPosition);
    }

    public override ContentPosition GetPagePosition(DocumentPage page)
    {
        return _originalPaginator.GetPagePosition(page);
    }

    private void SetPageSize(Size pageSize)
    {
        _originalPageSize = pageSize;

        // Decrease the available page size by the height of the header and footer. The page is offset by the header height later on.
        var sizeRect = new Rect(pageSize);
        sizeRect.Inflate(-HeaderAndFooterMarginWidth, -(HeaderAndFooterMarginHeight + _footerHeight/2 + _headerHeight/2));

        _originalPaginator.PageSize = _newPageSize = sizeRect.Size;

        // Change page size of the document to the size of the content area
        _paginatorSource.PageHeight = _newPageSize.Height;
        _paginatorSource.PageWidth = _newPageSize.Width;
    }

    public override bool IsPageCountValid
    {
        get { return _originalPaginator.IsPageCountValid; }
    }

    public override int PageCount
    {
        get { return _originalPaginator.PageCount; }
    }

    public override Size PageSize
    {
        get { return _newPageSize; }
        set { SetPageSize(value); }
    }

    public override IDocumentPaginatorSource Source
    {
        get { return _originalPaginator.Source; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi David, in your system. How did you rendered multiple flowdocuments into one XPS Document?

Comment: Hi, it's been a while now but I don't recall needing to. Does this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508173/how-to-concatenate-multiple-flowdocuments-together-into-1-flowdocument?

Comment: Hi, what I don't understand ist, what should those DataTemplates look like. For now I have Paragraphs inside my Flow document. I want to move them to the header, so that they appear at the beginning of every page. I didn't find out how to do this. Can anyone give me a clue?